# How much chlorine is there in 1 g of sodium dichloroisocyanurate?

Tags: concentration

According to Wikipedia, molar mass of anhydrous sodium dichloroisocyanurate is approximately 220 g per mole, and molar mass of Cl2 is 71 g per mole. Therefore there is 323 mg of chlorine in 1 g of NaDCC. But according to [this page](https://supply.unicef.org/s1588355.html), 33 mg of NaDCC releases 20 mg of chlorine, and so there is 606 mg of chlorine in 1 g of NaDCC. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: You're wrongfully assuming the amount of chlorine released is the same as the amount of chlorine contained in NADCC, but it does not dissociate completely.

Comment: By my calculations 33 mg of NaDCC would release 10.65 mg of chlorine, which is almost two times less than what that page claims.

Comment: In your page, "chlorine" isn't referring to $\ce{Cl2}$ but rather to $\ce{HOCl}$, which is released when added to water.

Comment: Assuming that all of the chlorine goes from NaDCC to HOCl, 33 mg of NaDCC would result in 15.75 mg of HOCl, which is still less than what is claimed on that page.

Comment: $\ce{HOCl}$ also partially dissociates into $\ce{OCl^-}$ ions, which are also accounted for in the 20 mg of chlorine produced.

Comment: @Sam202 OP is saying in that comment that if all the chlorine is turned into $\ce{HOCl}$, then that would be the mass. If you consider dissociation, the mass of the 'considered' active chlorine species would only decrease.

Comment: @M.L the addition of NaDCC to water is complex and involves around 10 equilibrium systems which all partially contribute to the total mass of chlorine disolved in water. Therefore, if only $\ce{NaDCC}$ dissociation is considered, there will be a deficit in amount of $\ce{Cl_2}$ produced.

Comment: @Sam202 Well the dissociation process might involve many steps, but ultimately, you should end up with active chlorine in the form of bleach.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the discrepancy comes with the $\ce{Na+}$. Each NaDCC has that positive ion. Since there is one $\ce{Na+}$ and two $\ce{Cl}$ per NaDCC. What I suspect happens is that there is that the page derives its values from calculating the abundance of two species: $\ce{NaClO}$ rather than $\ce{ClO-}$ and $\ce{HClO}$. The exact ratio between the two may not be 1:1, but I believe that the mass of all the $\ce{Na+}$ was included in the calculation of the amount of active chlorine.

Revising the calculation, you'd get about $\pu{19.0g}$ of chlorine species including $\ce{NaOCl}$ and $\ce{HOCl}$ with the following expression below (assuming the two species are in 1:1 ratio):

$$\frac{\pu{33 mg}}{\pu{220 g/mol}}\cdot MM(\ce{NaOCl)} + \frac{\pu{33 mg}}{\pu{220 g/mol}}\cdot MM(\ce{HOCl)} = \pu{19.0 g/mol}$$

This is much closer to what was reported. Note that the ratio of the two species is likely not 1:1. However, this would give the largest possible value as all the $\ce{Na+}$ is used up from NaDCC. I am not too sure how got and marketed the value of $\pu{20g}$, but I am guessing it has to do with what I mentioned above and maybe some slight bias in rounding.